# Android Audiotrack clicks before and after sound

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, audiotrack

I'm making synthesizer capable generate three basic types of sound and when I'm playing the sound, before and after it finishes playing click happen. And I can't figure it out why.

Happens with every type of sound.. with sine it is loudest.

Here is the code I use for generating sound

```
int amp = 32767;
double phase = 0.0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        AudioManager myAudioMgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        String nativeParam = myAudioMgr.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE);
        sampleRate = Integer.parseInt(nativeParam);
        nativeParam = myAudioMgr.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
        bufSize = Integer.parseInt(nativeParam);
    }
    else {
        sampleRate = 44100;
        bufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    }

    audioOutput = new AudioOutput();
    audioOutput.Start(sampleRate, bufSize);

    samples = new short[bufSize];    // buffer size is 512

    playTask.execute();
}

class PlayTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND + Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE);

        while (!this.isCancelled()) {
            while (touched) {
                generateTone();
                audioOutput.write(samples, 0, samples.length);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private void generateTone() {
    double phaseIncrement = (2 * Math.PI) / sampleRate;
    switch (currentShape) {
        case SINE:
            for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; i++) {
                samples[i] = (short) (amp * Math.sin(phase));
                phase += phaseIncrement * freq;
                if (phase > 2 * Math.PI)
                    phase -= 2 * Math.PI;
            }
            break;
        case SAWTOOTH:
            for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; i++) {
                samples[i] = (short) (amp * (phase - amp));
                phase += phaseIncrement * freq;
                if (phase > 2 * Math.PI)
                    phase -= 2 * Math.PI;
            }
            break;
        case SQUARE:
            for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; i++) {
                if (phase < Math.PI)
                    samples[i] = (short) amp;
                else
                    samples[i] = (short) -amp;
                phase += phaseIncrement * freq;
                if (phase > 2 * Math.PI)
                    phase -= 2 * Math.PI;
            }
            break;
    }
}

public class AudioOutput {
    private AudioTrack mAudioTrack;
    private int mFrameRate;

    public void Start(int sampleRate, int bufferSize) {
        Stop();
        mFrameRate = sampleRate;
        mAudioTrack = createAudioTrack(bufferSize);

        mAudioTrack.play();
    }

    private AudioTrack createAudioTrack(int buffsize) {
        return new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                mFrameRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffsize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    }

    public int write(short[] buffer, int offset, int length) {
        return write = mAudioTrack.write(buffer, offset, length);
    }

    public void Stop() {
        if (mAudioTrack != null) {
            mAudioTrack.stop();
            mAudioTrack.release();
            mAudioTrack = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Audio example: https://soundcloud.com/syntey/sinewavetest

Anyone know where could be a problem?

Thanks

Comment: can you give a link to the actual wave file? I think more information could be gleaned from looking at it than from listening to it.

Comment: Sure http://www.mediafire.com/download/hotb3wpz7q3v2jc/sinewave+test.wav

Comment: Are you doing a fade in/out anywhere in unlisted code? The generated signal clearly has some sort of envelope. Also the sine has a lot of distortion.

Comment: No, every code for generating sound is in this post

Comment: Fades are probably from microphone recording and I printed out buffer content and it's ok. That end is the only thing that bothers me

Comment: My point was that there is some amplitude control coming from somewhere other than the listed code. And that is quite possibly responsible for the pop.  If you zoom in on your wave file in audacity or similar you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: No, that's everything. Yes I see and that's why I created this question, because I don't know what could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't starting and ending each buffer at a zero crossing.  The random phase at the start of each buffer will likely produce too sharp a rise time transient into the very first sample.  Tapering (raised cosine taper) the first and last few dozen samples from zero and to zero might also help.

Comment: I fixed that reseting phase to 0, but I can't figure out that end. Do you know some programmed example of tapering? I tried to find something, but nothing.. Thanks